# What are the stats of a Beholden?

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, genius-the-transgression

One of the possible Merits of Genius: The Transgression is having one or more Beholden. They are an important part of the game, but it's not entirely clear to me what their stats are.

Do you roll them up as normal characters as per the World of Darkness core book and add the Beholden rules to them? Does this work differently? According to the Beholden Merit (p. 91) *"Beholden can hold a number of Mania points equal to their Intelligence + Resolve"*, which confirms that they indeed have stats.

In the back of the book (p. 464 and onwards) there are a number of example characters that the players might run into including a few Beholden, but from the looks of it they are quite a bit more experienced than freshly made characters. So how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a **person becomes** beholden, she loses the ability to recover
>   Willpower when indulging her Virtue or Vice

Page 91, Emphasis mine.  Like any other template in CoD, an NPC Beholden starts out as a Mortal, and becomes something else.  Page 278 further explains the process by which a beholden is created... in so much that there isn't anything to it.  They have Mortal stats, but regain willpower in a funky way... and that's about it.

Make a blue core book mortal npc, then convert them with the instructions on page 278, and you will have a fully stated beholden.

Comment: ctrl+f 'beholden' f3 * 500 And i found the answer pretty easily...